# How to get a new Column by PySpark?

Tags: python, pyspark

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzNte.png)

I want to get C4 by using formula,
for example ,when c1='104001',to calulate C4

Comment: Use withColumn() function, check the doc,http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html

Comment: Hey Dude, can you accept the answer if this question is done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this below to add another column:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

sc = SparkContext()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
l = [(25,24),[23,45],[24,56]]
rdd = sc.parallelize(l)
dummy = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(var1=int(x[0]),var2=int(x[1])))
dummyframe = sqlContext.createDataFrame(dummy)


def getValDivideSum(dataFrame):
    max = dataFrame.agg({"var2":'sum'}).collect()[0][0]
    dataFrame = dataFrame.withColumn("var3",dataFrame.var2/max).select("var1","var2","var3")
    return dataFrame
```

Output will be something like this:

```
+----+----+-----+
|var1|var2| var3|
+----+----+-----+
|  25|  24|0.192|
|  23|  45| 0.36|
|  24|  56|0.448|
+----+----+-----+
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @7125messi let me know if it solves the problem. If yes, please accept the answer.